Blow-up of irreducible/reduced is irreducible/reduced
Let $Y$ be some scheme and $X$ be a closed subscheme of $Y$ corresponding to a finite type quasicoherent sheaf of ideals. I was trying to do Exercise 22.2.C of Vakil's "The Rising Sea":
"Show that if $Y$ is irreducible, and $X$ doesn’t contain the generic point of $Y$, then the blow-up $B$ of $Y$ at $X$ is irreducible. Show that if $Y$ is reduced, then $B$ is reduced."
I've found some solutions for this question online (Blowup of $\mathbb{P}^n$ at a point is irreducible for irreducibility, Blow up of reduced scheme is reduced for reducedness).
However, when Vakil presents this problem, the only definition he gave of a blow-up is by its universal property, involving effective Cartier divisors. Do you know any way of proving irreducibility and reducedness using only the universal property?
